# Problem with jQuery validation. Error message is popping up in the wrong place

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-validate

My form code is like this (MVC 2)

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()){ %>
  <%: Html.Serialize("regData", Model)%>
  <div class="RegistrationGroup">
    <p><label for="FirstName">First name</label>  <%: Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstName) %><span class="ErrorMessage"></span></p>
    <p><label for="LastName">Last name</label>  <%: Html.EditorFor(x => x.LastName) %><span class="ErrorMessage"></span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="RegistrationGroup">
    <input name="nextButton" type="image" src="../../Images/button_next.png" alt="Neste" />
  </div>
<% } %>
```

Then in my script, I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  $("#Email").focus();
  $("form").validate({
    rules: {
      FirstName: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
      },
      LastName: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
      }
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
      error.appendTo(element.next());
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

My problem is that all validation errors appear between the label and the textbox and looks pretty bad. I want to put the error message inside *ErrorMessage* span that is put right after the actual input elements, and I have tried numerous variants inside the `errorPlacement` part of the options to validate. The error message always appear in the same spot regardless.

This looks correct to me, so if anyone knows where I did the wrong turn here, I'll be grateful.

Comment: @mu - It gives the following HTML: `<input class="text-box single-line" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" />`, so a quite normal text box.

Comment: It works as expected here: http://jsfiddle.net/mzMER/ It can be the css, you can post some css as well.

Comment: @dioslaska - it is probably the css, because I checked the html after validation now in the developer tools in Chrome, and it seems that the following markup is added inside the ErrorMessage span: <label for="FirstName" generated="true" class="error">please enter your first name</label>

Comment: I didn't expect it to add the error message inside a label. Are there any way to get it to only put the validation text as plain text, and not as a label itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the error to appear inside label tags, put in your errorPlacement function:

```
element.next().append(error.text());
```

Comment: Worked as a charm :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was a little quick there actually. Now, all error messages get appended and never gets cleared. The same validation error may actually be shown several times after each other. I replaced append with html, and then the error message does not append but gets replaced as wanted, but when the input is made legal, the validation error is not cleared. Any idea how to get it cleared?

Comment: @dioslaka - I reverted to using the label and styling it properly using css now. No need to try to be to clever when it works fine :)